# SMART Gwt Code Splitting

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

We are using SmartGwt 2.5 and application is very large.
I want to know is there any way to implement Code Splitting or Partial JS loading in SmartGWT.
Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gwt's code splitting directly in SmartGwt. 
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

Comment: Hi Jai.. Thanks for reply. Can you provide any example ?. Some Post on Google Groups regarding Code Splitting says that It can not be done.

Comment: I have done it. So yes... it works. The doc itself is a good example, nothing new to be done there, however, you are better advised to create sensible chunks of loadable code.