# Plug-in based UI Architecture using GWT

Tags: gwt, plugins, architecture

I have a requirement of developing a Plug-in based UI architecture. Currently, my app uses GWT (Google-Tool-kit) as a client side technology. Now, I am looking for making the app more modular and plugin-aware.

For example, I should have my UI framework ready and any other developers can develop their UI and install/run it as part of my framework. My Framework should never have the GWT code from other developers and compile them as part of the framework.

But the problem I get is, GWT expects all the codes to be compiled together and output the javascript/html which doesn't solve my purpose.

Is there anybody who is also thinking on the same line/ developing something like this? It would be a great help to get me started with some data point/sample code/app.

Thanks in advance.

-Tapas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654544/smart-gwt-code-splitting).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But I don't think it is the duplicate of one you pointed out. I am not looking for a code splitting kind of solution. Code splitting certainly solves the problem of different module loading but it doesn't address the issue of separateness in compilation of different modules and link them dynamically at run time.

Comment: Ok. Let's look forward to a better solution.

Comment: @TapasAdhikary It's been more than 8 years now... Have you found any solution to this? I'm also looking for the same thing.

Comment: @pavi2410, I have moved on and rewritten the solution with the react long ago. Haven't really tried exploring much about it since 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Do the plugin developers have to develop in GWT? If you want to expose a Javascript API to developers, then you can look at GWT-Js interop API project: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-api-interop/

Comment: No.. It is not necessary, plug-in developers need to build in GWT.. but giving option to build them in GWT would be desirable. If we can build and support a javascript API, that also should be fine.. But with javascript, the only issue come in my mind is maintainability when it grows..